# Python AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Tags: python, object, attributes, attributeerror, nonetype

I'm trying to scrap a simple website. but facing issue with "NoneType" object has no attribute "find". can anyone help to find out what is the problem with it

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
root = "https://subslikescript.com/"
website = f"{root}/movies"

result = requests.get(website)
content = result.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
# print(soup.prettify())

box = soup.find('article', class_= 'main-article')
link_list = []
for link in box.find_all('a', href = True):
    link_list.append(link['href'])
print(link_list)

for link in link_list:
    website = f"{root}/{link}"
    result = requests.get(website)
    content = result.text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
    box = soup.find('article', class_='main-article')
    heading = box.find('h1').get_text()

    transcript = box.find('div', class_="full-script").get_text(strip = True, separator = ' ')

    with open(heading+".txt", 'w', encoding="utf-8") as file:
        file.write(transcript)
```

I tried this

```
box = soup.find('article', {"class": 'main-article'})
```

Comment: Which line is the error pointing to? You call `.find()` a few times throughout your code.

Comment: soup.find() is returning None

Comment: That website is broken. e.g., https://subslikescript.com/movie/Blind_Detective-2332707 results in HTTP 500